# How to separate 10 attributes with Rapidminer?

Tags: rapidminer

I have an excel file with a lot of data.I want to find 10 columns where cause best separation.
I want to do this with rapid miner.
(sorry my English is not good)

Comment: Can you say what you have tried so far? Perhaps an example would help. What do you mean by separation and how many columns and rows do you have in the original data?

Comment: I have 12623 rows and 530 columns(attributes). I want to find 10 best attribute that separate my datas.

Comment: What do you mean by separate? Do you mean with respect to a label or perhaps you suspect the rows form into clusters?

Comment: in classification some attributes are more important than others . I want to specify 10 attributes that are more important for classification.
the problem is classification not clustering.
:(

Comment: Sorry to labour the point but do you have a class against which to classify the attributes?

Comment: Yes! The last column is label. Would you help me plzzz?? :(

Comment: would you help me plz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the `Weight By` operators such as `Weight By Correlation`, to create a set of attribute weights where the weight of an attribute represents how predictive it is of the class label. You can then use the `Select By Weight` operator to select the desired number of attributes. Set the parameters of this operator to `weight relation` to `top k` and `k` to `10`. The inputs to this operator are the attribute weights and the example set which are output by the `Weight By` operator.